# Error message for immediate attribute

Tags: java, jsf

See the following code:

```
<h:form>
   <table> 
     <tr>                 
     <td> 
       <h:inputText id="name" value="#{jsfBean.name }" required="true" immediate="true"/>
      <h:message for="name"/>
    </td>
 </tr>
     <tr>                 
        <td> 
      <h:inputText id="number" value="#{jsfBean.number }" required="true" />
      <h:message for="number"/>
    </td>
 </tr>          
 <tr>
    <td>
         <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{jsfBean.submit }" immediate="true"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
     </table>
    </h:form>
```

When I am submitting the form without typing the values, It should validate and throw error for first text box. But, its not happening. What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks fine. To be sure, I even copypasted it into my JSF 2.0.3 / Tomcat 7.0.5 environment. Works fine. Are you certain that you're running the code you think you're running? What JSF impl/version are you using? What servletcontainer impl/version are you using? Don't you have any event/phaselisteners which might be disturbing the phases? (e.g. by calling `facesContext.renderResponse()` too soon)

Comment: i am using the latest implementation. I confused why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working for me

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">


</faces-config>
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>

            <h:inputText value="#{myBean.val}" required="true" immediate="true"/>
            <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.submit}" immediate="true"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

libraries

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#AddImmediateTrueToUIInputAndUICommand. Read the section.

Comment: `3 Process validations This phase is skipped due to the immediate="true" in the h:commandButton.` Yes thats it.

Comment: Read the Apply request values section completely.

Comment: ah..yes Are you applying custom validator or this is just `required="true"` ?

Comment: Krishna is right. It's supposed to work. A button with immediate=true will only validate inputs with immediate=true. The given code example should show required message on 1st field and nothing on 2nd field whenever fields are left blank.

Comment: @BalusC Yes locally implemented and tested , it is showing me error , i mean validation is there

Comment: May be its some problem with my version. Please update your answer. SO that I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I have added my configuration and code that was tested , you can verify with it

Answer (score 0):

Because its immediate=true. Immediate fields skip the validation step. I think you have to validate this field manually.

Comment: From my understanding, when UIInput and UIcommand is set immediate is true, UIInput will be validated in the Apply Request Values phase.

Comment: Wrong answer. Readup here http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html